# Wildlife site request

Tags: feature-request

I've been curious for quite a while why you don't have a specific site pertaining to wildlife. From a cursory perusal of other online sites, it seems like it would be a very popular, well-used,  and welcome addition. I hesitate to postulate ,(but will anyway) that it could be a heck of a lot more popular/helpful than some of the other seemingly relatively obscure subjects.  I can't be the only one who has a myriad of questions (and occasional answers) about our feathered, furry, and scaly friends.

Comment: wouldn't some aspects also be on-topic on [Biology.se](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) does cover wildlife questions.

Comment: @snow. The Great Outdoors site offers some advice in this area, but seems to encompass a much broader range -- i.e. most of what I see is more about hiking, camping, recreational activities than it is about the wildlife.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions may be on topic on an existing site:

- [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com): questions about wildlife are [on topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/971/phenomena-observed-outdoors-we-need-better-criteria-to-determine-whether-they/978#978)

  - Example: [Can Cormorants swallow and digest large prey like eels whole?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/can-cormorants-swallow-and-digest-large-prey-like-eels-whole)
- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com): for more academic questions

  - Example: [How do birds influence brood sex ratios?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/how-do-birds-influence-brood-sex-ratios)
- [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com): for the ones that aren’t wild.

  - Example: [Can tamed foxes and pigs live peacefully together?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/can-tamed-foxes-and-pigs-live-peacefully-together?r=SearchResults)